# Stripes format type format pattern number not working properly

Tags: java, jsp-tags, stripes, tld

I have a Stripes JSP with a `<stripes:form>` tag etc.
I have a line like the following one:

```
<span class='amount'>
    <fmt:formatNumber value="${MyJavaClass.amount}" type="number"/>
</span>
```

I know this is working fine in combination with the corresponding Stripes Action Bean.

Now I want to format that "amount" variable in a different way, i.e. being sure that at least 2 decimals are used.
For example:

> 199.1 becomes 199.10
>   362.44 remains 362.44

I thought that adding a `formatPattern="decimal"` would have been enough, according to Stripes documentation.
**Please note that I want to keep the "number" format type, I do not want to change it to be a currency type.**
Actually I am experiencing errors like the following one:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /MyJSPPath/MyJSP.jsp(19,6) Attribute formatPattern invalid for tag formatNumber according to TLD
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it setting properly the `pattern` parameter.

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${MyJavaClass.amount}" type="number" pattern="#.00"/>
```

This was not enough:

```
<fmt:formatNumber value="${MyJavaClass.amount}" type="number" maxFractionDigits="2"/>
```

The issue related to only one digit was still there (i.e. "199.3" was still "199.3", rather than "199.30")